# How to resolve an IllegalStateException: User not found in JUnit test?

Tags: java, spring, junit

for testing I want to create a user object and save it for later reference with:

```
    User user = userService.createUserInformation("testl", "testpw", "peter", "tester", "test@test.de", "en");
```

Inside that, there is a call to save the user:

```
    public User createUserInformation(...)
       User newUser = new User();
       Authority authority = authorityRepository.findOne("ROLE_USER");
       ...
       newUser.setAuthorities(authorities);
       userRepository.save(newUser);
     }
```

But when I try this, I get a:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: User not found!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: User not found!
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:381)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy166.save(Unknown Source)
    at app.backend.service.UserService.createUserInformation(UserService.java:111)
    at
```

What does this means (User not found, while I want to save it?) How can I see more details of the User object, or how to fix this problem?

The test configuration is based on an AbstractControllerTest:

```
  @WebAppConfiguration
  @ContextConfiguration  
  @ActiveProfiles({"dev", "test"})
  public class AbstractControllerTest extends AbstractTest {
```

(not sure where to find the exact app configuration for test)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: post your createUserInformation and configuration

Comment: ok, i added some more infos, not sure where to find the app configuration exactly, there is no XML file but a class that might load the liquibase connection - info's how to properly make a configuration for test would be helpful too

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your test environment, hibernate isn't able to find entities or connect to your database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that only a logged in user is allowed to create a new user. So, I mock the logged in user with:

```
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SecurityUtils.class);
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

        CustomUserDetails userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(new Long(1), "test12", "testpw", authorities, true, true, true, true);
        PowerMockito.when(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUser()).thenReturn(userDetails);

        User user = userService.createUserInformation("testl", "testpw", "peter", "tester", "test@test.de", "en");
```

Feels not ideal, but it works for now. (Better might be to have some test users in a seed database, but not sure how to do this)